# Responsive image aspect ratio of height

Tags: html, css

I have an image of 768px x 432px. I make it responsive, but I want the aspect ratio to be calculated based on the value of 350px x 250px.

I can do this with the width but not with the height.

How could I do it?

What am I using for width:

```
.thumb {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

```css
.thumb {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-4">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/768/432/technics/" class="thumb">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try in the css using  the vh /vw tags for responsive cross platform page fitting.

for example:
vh - view-height
vw - viewwidth

```
.thumb {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30vw;
  max-height: 25vh;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

Just a side note, When your thinking of page width -- imagine the full page width being 100vw so 30vw would basically be a bit less than a third of the page no matter the size of a page. same idea with the height.